# How can I find the remaining rows in the SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I use two data source (tables) `ODS.dbo.Account_Address__c` and `PAF.dbo.Delivery_Addresses` to make a statistical summary about the address data in table `ODS.dbo.Account_Address__c`. Table `PAF.dbo.Delivery_Addresses` was for look-up  and inner join.

All data of interest is all rows since `CreatedDate=2016-09-28` and also those with `IsCurrent=1` prior to `2016-09-28`.

**Table 1**:

```
SELECT DPID__c,CreatedDate
FROM ODS.dbo.Account_Address__c
WHERE CreatedDate>='2016-09-28'

UNION ALL

SELECT DPID__c,CreatedDate
FROM ODS.dbo.Account_Address__c
WHERE CreatedDate<'2016-09-28' AND IsCurrent=1
```

There are totally `265773 rows`.

Then I subset the data by inner join with `PAF.dbo.Delivery_Addresses`,`241565 rows` were returned.

**Table 2**:

```
SELECT 
     aa.DPID__c, aa.CreatedDate     
FROM 
     ODS.dbo.Account_Address__c aa ,PAF.dbo.Delivery_Addresses da
WHERE
     aa.DPID__c = CONVERT(VARCHAR,da.DELIVERY_POINT_ID)
     AND aa.CreatedDate>='2016-09-28'
     AND aa.DPID__c IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
     aa.DPID__c,aa.CreatedDate
FROM    
     ODS.dbo.Account_Address__c aa ,PAF.dbo.Delivery_Addresses da
WHERE
     aa.DPID__c = CONVERT(VARCHAR,da.DELIVERY_POINT_ID)
     AND aa.CreatedDate<'2016-09-28'
     AND aa.DPID__c IS NOT NULL
     AND aa.IsCurrent=1
```

Subsequently I also check two other subsets.

**Table 3**:

NULL `DPID__c` of `11170 rows`:

```
SELECT DPID__c,CreatedDate
FROM ODS.dbo.Account_Address__c
WHERE CreatedDate>='2016-09-28' AND DPID__c IS NULL 

UNION ALL

SELECT DPID__c,CreatedDate
FROM ODS.dbo.Account_Address__c
WHERE CreatedDate<'2016-09-28' AND IsCurrent=1 AND DPID__c IS NULL
```

And reject inner join set, `12982 rows` returned.

**Table 4**:

```
SELECT a.DPID__c,a.CreatedDate
FROM
(
 SELECT DPID__c,CreatedDate
 FROM ODS.dbo.Account_Address__c
 WHERE CreatedDate>='2016-09-28' AND DPID__c IS NOT NULL

 UNION ALL

 SELECT DPID__c,CreatedDate
 FROM ODS.dbo.Account_Address__c
 WHERE CreatedDate<'2016-09-28' AND DPID__c IS NOT NULL AND IsCurrent=1
) a

EXCEPT

SELECT t.DPID__c,t.CreatedDate
FROM
(
 SELECT 
    aa.DPID__c, aa.CreatedDate      
 FROM   
    ODS.dbo.Account_Address__c aa ,PAF.dbo.Delivery_Addresses da
 WHERE
    aa.DPID__c = CONVERT(VARCHAR,da.DELIVERY_POINT_ID)
    AND aa.CreatedDate>='2016-09-28'
    AND aa.DPID__c IS NOT NULL

 UNION ALL

 SELECT
   aa.DPID__c, aa.CreatedDate           
 FROM   
   ODS.dbo.Account_Address__c aa ,PAF.dbo.Delivery_Addresses da
 WHERE
   aa.DPID__c = CONVERT(VARCHAR,da.DELIVERY_POINT_ID)
   AND aa.CreatedDate<'2016-09-28'
   AND aa.DPID__c IS NOT NULL
   AND aa.IsCurrent=1
 ) t
```

As verified, `Count_Row(Table 1)>Count_Row(Table 2)+Count_Row(Table 3)+Count_Row(Table 4)` and still have `56` extra rows in `Table 1` but not in any other tables.

Could anyone help to suggest how this gap could occur and how can I detect the remaining `56 rows`?

Cheers

Comment: `UNION ALL` Table2, 3 and 4 and `EXCEPT` the result from Table1. If you have nothing returned that means these 56 rows are exact duplicates of some of the rows in Table2 and/or 3 and/or 4.

Comment: @Alex thanks for good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `except` removes duplicates. you should use an `except all`. 
Unfortunately SQL server doesn't have `except all`, but that is probably where your lines are dropped.

Check the unique lines in each query, you should have the same number.

Comment: Thank you Steven. The duplicate removal was the problem.